# Can not import tweepy for python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

Using jupyter notebook

```
import tweepy
```

However, i get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-2-f5e4f2180e08>", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.7.egg\tweepy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.7.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 358
    def _start(self, async):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do I do to resolve this problem? When i run conda list in command prompt, it says.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    tweepy                    3.6.0                     <pip>
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` may not be used as an argument name in Python 3.7.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights

> **async** and **await** are now reserved keywords.

This issue is already known: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017

The current recommendation is to manually rename all occurrences of `async` to `async_` in /tweepy/streaming.py until a new release is available.